# python bottle redirect resulting in Error 405 : Method not allowed

Tags: python-3.x, redirect, http-post, bottle, http-status-code-405

So I've been working or a quick small project and I have that issue

```
from bottle import get, post, request, run, redirect
import threading 

@get('/button')
def button():
    return '''
        <form action="/button" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Push"/>
        </form>
    '''
@post
def action():
    print ("button pushed")
    global pushed 
    pushed = True
    redirect("/button")


threading.Thread(target=run, kwargs=dict(host='localhost', port=80)).start()

pushed = False
print("Started")
while 1:

    if pushed:
        print("push recv")
        pushed = False
```

I'm running my code using "sudo python3 code.py"

Comment: Please include the HTTP call that you're making to your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't attached a route to your `@post` declaration. It should be:

```
@post('/button')
```

Comment: that was such a dummy mistake! thanks for pointing that out <3